# Small monitor for laptop with touchscreen

Tags: monitors, touchscreen

I am looking for a monitor of 16 inches or less, that could get conected to my laptop and using it as a second screen.I don't mind if it is portable or not, but I would like it to be touch screen.

I know that screen of this kind are [available](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=HDMI_Interface_5_Inch_800x480_TFT_Display) for Raspberr Pi. But is it possible to use this kind of screens as second screen for a laptop?

Does anybody knows any other screen that could be used the way I explained?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't make a particular recommendation, but if you simply google "external touch screen", plenty of candidates pop up...

Comment: Yeah, but of 16 inches or less, only appear the ones related to Raspberry Pi or other boards... @SEJPM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So small and simple, but you can use this display with any computer that has HDMI output, and the shape makes it easy to attach to a electronic product. Although the 800x480 common HDMI display is made for Raspberry Pi, we can use it other where not only for Raspberry Pi.

Description of the product from your link.

That product will work with any computer, provided it has an HDMI output.